# Adding ManyToMany extra field to QuerySet in django

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

Suppose I have following models:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ratings = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', through='Rating')

class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing')
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

So I have a lot of things, and every user can rate every thing. I also have a view showing a list of all things (and they are huge in numbers) with a rating that user assigned to each of them. I need a way to retreive all the data from database: Thing objects with additional field `user_rating` taken from at most one (because we have a fixed User) related Rating object.

Trivial solution looks like that:

```
things = Thing.objects.all()
for thing in things:
    try:
        thing.user_rating = thing.ratings.objects.get(user=request.user).rating
    except Rating.DoesNotExist:
        thing.user_rating = None
```

But the flaw of this approach is obvious: if we have 500 things, we'll do 501 requests to database. Per one page. Per user. And this is the most viewed page of the site. This task is easily solvable with SQL JOINs but in practice I have more complicated schema and I will certainly benefit from Django model framework. So the question is: is it possible to do this Django-way? It would be really strange if it isn't, considering that such tasks are very common.

As I understood, neither `annotate()`, nor `select_related()` will help me here.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you should try this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Example

```
result = Thing.objects.all().extra(select={'rating': 'select rating from ratings where thing_id = id'})
```

Your result set gets a new field 'rating' for each 'thing' object.

I use this approach in one of my recent projects. It produces one complex query instead of n+1 queries.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Looks a lot nicer, thanks. It will execute nested SELECT, do I understand correctly? So basically database performs same amount of job, and JOIN would still be preferrable.

Comment: you can overlook the query by printing connection.queries, there is also another approach, you could write a custom raw sql query (using connection.cursor)

Comment: the amount of job is different, one transaction, one database connection, one nested query (instead of n+1 queries), it's relatively fast

Comment: Will F expressions not be the safest way? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F

Comment: @radtek it's been over three years since I proposed the solution. If I get the documentation right, F expressions were added in django 1.8 (5 versions later). If there's a modern solution that produces the same result and is more elegant, you're more than welcome to create an alternate answer.

Comment: F expressions were added in 1.7, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/ . I don't have an example for many to many relationships but I did add an extra field queryset using them along with annotate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are planning to display everything in one page. I can think of this approach. You can give this a try:

Get all the ratings given by the current user and Get all the Things.

Now try to create a dictionary like this:

```
thing_dict = {}

for thing in Thing.objects.all():
    thing_dict[thing] = None
for rating in Rating.objects.filter(user = request.user):
    thing_dict[rating.thing] = rating
```

Now thing_dict contains all the entries of model Thing as keys and has its rating as its value.

May not be the best way. I am keen on seeing what others answer.

Comment: You've still got a query for each user instead of an aggregation.

Comment: Okay, but it's certainly not perfect. What if things are split in pages? Say, there are 10000 things and page contain 100 entries. Second loop will have to look through all of the possible 10000 ratings.

Comment: @Tom at least there are 2 queries instead of n+1

Comment: @user285176, it surely is a bad idea if we are splitting it across many pages. Depending on how many things will be rated by a user, we can think of storing the rating information in a de-normalized way.